# Mysite getting too slow due to dns lookup

Tags: domain-name-system

When I'm loading my site, its getting too slow and its mainly because of slow dnslookup. It hardly taking 28.77s to load the site. My site is hosted on godaddy.

Do anyone have any idea to speed up my site?

Comment: I find it exceptionally hard to believe DNS lookups take that long. How are you coming to that conclusion?

Comment: Actually I concluded by viewing the details while right clicking "inspect element" on browser. Also I tried to upload the screen shot, but as a new user, I couldn't upload any photos here for now. 

Do I have any problems with my site http headers ?

Comment: I've seen Firefox's Firebug misreport long DNS lookup times on a page with many external resources (images, css, js, etc.) in instances where HTTP keepalive was not enabled on the server. Try running it through PageSpeed and see what it says: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you host your website using wordpress, then disable all plugins, CDN service in case if you have any CDN and try to reload it